# How would I be able to test this code using jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm about to build a widget, and I want to use Jasmine to test the code, and one of the things I want to test is that changeHtml has been called. Here's a rough example of how I was planning on building the widget.

```
var widget = function(userOptions){
  var options = userOptions

  var init = function(){
    changeHtml();
  };

  var changeHtml = function(){
    document.getElementById(options.widgetId).innerHTML = 'New and exiting things!';
  };

  init();
};

var myWidget = new widget({widgetId: 'widget-div'});
```

Now, because `changeHtml()` is a private (correct phrase?) function of `widget`, I can't spy on it to see if it has been called or not.

The only thing I can think of at the moment, is make everything a public method of `widget`, but that doesn't seem particularly good because the user wouldn't have to/want to call `changeHtml()` their self.

What would be a solution to this? Or, am I think about this in the wrong way, would it be better to check if the divs innerHTML has actually been changed rather than the function being called?

Comment: Your last sentence sums it up. The method call is an implementation detail. You want to test the result, it's not really important how it gets there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either 1) test the end result, or 2) `spyOn` functions that have been exposed in functions/objects.

To test the end result in your scenario, you would need to either check the HTML value after it changes, or check that it was called so the value could be set, like this:

```
describe("widget", function () {
    it("Should change html", function () {
        // Arrange
        spyOn(document, "getElementById").and.callThrough();

        // Act
        var myWidget = new widget({ widgetId: 'widget-div' });

        // Assert
        expect(document.getElementById).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```